# post thumbnail: increase dimension if smaller than... Possible?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I need thumbnails of minimum width: 400px.

I would like that if the user uploads an image that is, say, 380px wide, Wordpress creates a 400px-wide version.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not. But you can set up a css rule like min-width:"400px" for the thumbnails